# AngularJS not listening to all my fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS with Rails and creating dynamic nested form items which are not registering in the AngularJS scope. They are assigned the 'ng-dirty' class.

I have an investor which has three houses, in my Angular controller I only assign the first 2 as I really want to set these through Rails instead.

```
$ (event) ->
  app = angular.module "investor", []

  app.controller("InvestorCtrl", ["$scope", ($scope) ->
    $scope.houses = [
      { cost: "295000", value: "450000" },
      { cost: "600000", value: "620000"  }    
    ]
    $scope.calc_totals = ->
      # Initialise variables
      cost = 0
      value = 0

      # Go through each house and calculate the total cost
      for h in $scope.houses
        cost = parseInt(cost) + parseInt(h.cost)
        value = parseInt(value) + parseInt(h.value)

      # Set the total
      $scope.total_cost = cost
      $scope.total_value = value  

    # Run the calculation at the start  
    # $scope.calc_totals()
  ])

  angular.bootstrap document, ['investor']
```

Here is my form

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "InvestorCtrl"}
    = form_for(@investor) do |f|
        - if @investor.errors.any?
            #error_explanation
                %h2
                    = pluralize(@investor.errors.count, "error")
                    prohibited this investor from being saved:
                %ul
                    - @investor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                        %li= msg
        .field
            = f.label :name
            = f.text_field :name, "ng-model" => "name"

        - i = 0
        = f.fields_for :houses do |builder|
            .field
                = render :partial => "house", :locals => {:f => builder, :i => i}
                - i = i + 1

        .field
            = f.label :total_cost
            = f.number_field :total_cost, "ng-model" => "total_cost"
        .field
            = f.label :total_value
            = f.number_field :total_value, "ng-model" => "total_value"
        .actions
            = f.submit
```

If I type in the first or second house 'cost' or 'value' then it updates the total_cost, but if I update the third house it will not update the total_cost.

Is there a way to dynamically tell angularjs to listen to these elements without assigning them in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually going about this a little wrong, IMO. Since Angular can (and will) be handling the rendering of your repeating HTML for you, you don't necessarily *need* to do your HTML rendering on the server. All you need from your server is some JSON.  If you want it to be rendered right off the bat, you just make sure your initial values are set up properly when you initialize your controller.

Inject $http or a custom made service into your controller, and pull the data you want directly from the server in JSON format, then plug it into your scope. If your HTML and directives are set up properly it will just render. From there all other logic will be the same.

The web is moving forward. And by forward, I mean all of that HTML rendering stuff you used to do on the server is actually starting to be done on the client more and more. And that service layer you used to use to get your data on your web server? Well it *is* your web server now.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your problem, but it will greatly simplify what you're trying to do. Otherwise you have a balancing act to perform that will get maddening pretty fast.

Comment: Should I stop using haml also and use static html templates with AngularJS?

Comment: Well, you could use haml to define your html, I suppose... But I wouldn't use server side logic to render any data into your html... Let Angular handle that.

Comment: What about creating the links using 'link_to' or should I do that also through Angular and start using the routing feature?

Comment: If the links are just a part of your overall layout, then use whatever, but if they're part of a data driven control or piece of functionality, let angular build them. the point is that if you have the server building html from your data AND you have angular doing the same on the client, you're probably wasting effort. Just send the data to angular and let the client do the work.

Comment: So I found this tutorial is this what you are talking about: http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2012/09/tutorials-on-angularjs-and-rails.html